# Moving the cursor in an UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I try to move the cursor when a `UITextView` is selected(touched) to simulate kind of a `UITextField placeholder` thing.

I'd like the cursor to be at the beginning of the first line. My problem is, that `[someTextField setSelectedRange]`is not working reliably. When I call it in `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` it works as it should. But this method is only called when the user starts typing. I'm using `textViewDidBeginEditing:` to move the cursor when the `UITextView` becomes the first responder:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView == self.descriptionText) {
        CustomTextView* customTV = (CustomTextView *)textView;
        if ([customTV.text isEqualToString:customTV.placeholder]) {
            // text in text view is still the placeholder -> move cursor to the beginning
            customTV.text = customTV.placeholder;
            customTV.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            customTV.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why `customTV.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);` isn't working correctly in `textViewDidBeginEditing:` ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you find the solution to this ?

Comment: A solution answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310035/force-uitextview-cursor-to-the-top-of-the-view/29310666#29310666

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's a very simple way of accomplishing this.

```
    // Count the characters on screen
    NSMutableString *numOfChar = [self.myTextField.text mutableCopy];

    // Skip that many characters to the left
    self.myTextField.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(self.myTextField.selectedRange.location-[numOfChar length], 0);
```

Hope this helps.